# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query,I need help on this

```
SELECT MIN(Time) 
FROM `TABLE 1` 
WHERE LevelGuidance="High Guidance" 
AND Task=1 IN (SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE Task_ Difficulty="Low")
```

Comment: Thats not a valid sql syntax what are trying to do with sub-query

Comment: I want to execute this query 'What is the minimum time taken to complete a Task 1  with high guidance in low difficulty?'.. My table has all of these attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sub-query or even IN operator all you need is just an another condition

```
SELECT MIN(Time) 
FROM `TABLE 1` 
WHERE LevelGuidance='High Guidance' 
AND Task_Difficulty='Low'
AND Task=1
```

Comment: I want to get the results for Task 1 as well. There are two tasks that is Task 1 and Task 2.

Comment: @MannyYog - Updated check now

Comment: I executed the same query before but I was getting error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Difficulty="Low" AND Task=1' at line 4"

Comment: @MannyYog - reove space between `Task_ Difficulty` also replace double quotes with single quotes. Updated try now

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got It. There was a mistake in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is written wrong. To fix it you'll need to add a specific column before the IN () operator. Also, you'll need to specify which column the IN operator is looking at

Example

```
SELECT MIN(Time) FROM TABLE 1 WHERE LevelGuidance="High Guidance" AND Task=1 and SOMEcolumn IN (SELECT SOMEcolumn FROM TABLE 1 WHERE Task_ Difficulty="Low")
```

More on the IN operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Can we use 'AND' thrice?

Comment: You can use the AND operator as many times as you need. However, each time you use it, it forces the results to be more and more specific.

Comment: If your subquery is actually the same table as the one main select, you don't need to use the IN, just use another AND.